# Understanding `extern` storage class specifier in C

Tags: c, extern

Consider given C codes :

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int i;
int main(){
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives `Compilation error`. While if I  initialize `extern int i=10;` then output is `10`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int i=10; //initialization statement
int main(){
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

And also, if I assign `int i=10;`then output is `10`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 extern int i;
 int i=10;  //assignment
int main(){
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
#include<stdio.h>
 extern int i;
 int main(){
    int i=10;   //assignment
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Variation :

```
#include<stdio.h>
 extern int i;
 int i=20;
 int main(){
    int i=10;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Since, `int i` is local variable, so output is `10`.

> > Please, can you explain some important point about `extern` storage class in C

---

I read somewhere, a declaration declares the name and type of variable or function. A definition causes storage to be allocated for the variable or the body of the function to be defined. The same variable or function may have many declaration, but there can be only one defition for that variable or function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the extern storage class. Remove it and see.

Comment: Read about the _declaration_ vs. _definition_. And `int i = 10;` is not an assignment! You cannot have expressions outside a function body. What does your C book say? What is your **specific** problem? (This is no tutoring site)

Comment: "Extern" isn't a storage class. It's a storage class *specifier*.

Comment: @KerrekSB, thanks for correction.

Comment: Surely case 1 gives linking error, not compilation error (if you want generic term, you can say build error)... Also, please always include the exact error in SO questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider

```
int i;
```

declared outside all the functions of the programme including `main`.

This means `i` will have

- file scope
- static storage duration
- space is allocated for i. #This is important.

Consider

```
extern int i;
```

declared outside all the functions of the programme including `main`.
This means `i` will have

- file scope
- static storage duration
- `i` is only declared, not defined which means space is not allocated.
- `i` is assumed to be defined somewhere else, may be, in an include file

Consider

```
extern int i=10;
```

declared outside all the functions of the programme including `main`.
This is the case where you're initializing the `extern` variable `i`. In this case

- Space is allocated for `i`.
- i will be initialized to `10`.
- The keyword `extern` is neglected which means `i` is NOT `declared only`.

---

**Note**

For `extern int i` it is mandatory that the variable should be defined somewhere else, ie in another source file. If this is not the case, you will a compile-time error.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay : Thanks for accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

The extern storage class specifier  is used to give a reference of a global variable that is visible to ALL the program files. When you use 'extern', the variable cannot be initialized however, it points the variable name at a storage location that has been previously defined.

Comment: _it points the variable name at a storage location that has been previously defined?_, any example, please?

Comment: When you have multiple files and you define a global variable or function, which will also be used in other files, then extern will be used in another file to provide the reference of defined variable or function. Just for understanding, extern is used to declare a global variable or function in another file. @MithleshUpadhyay

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

when the code references a symbol via the `extern` modifier, it means the symbol is actually defined elsewhere rather than in the current file.

An exception, if the `extern` modififier is used for a symbol that is actually defined in the current file, that is OK.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `extern int i;` declaration just tells the compiler that there somewhere (in this or another source) exists an actual declaration of `i` in global scope. It's not in itself the actual declaration of `i`. Therefore it's inappropriate to assign a value to `i` in that declaration (which is why the second try is invalid). Your first attempt is invalid since you don't have an actual declaration of `i`.

Your third is OK though as you have an actual declaration of `i`, but you wouldn't have to have the `extern int i;` declaration.

Your last samples involves `i` in both local and global scope. In such a case the variable in local scope will be used. That's why you don't get 20 printed.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: There is no "global scope" in C. `extern` is not about scope.

Comment: it is used to give a reference of a global variable.

Comment: @Olaf What then do you call the scope of global variables? `extern` declarations always refers to global variables (even if they appear inside a function).