# Lifetime of "extern" variable in C?

Tags: c, extern, lifetime

What is the lifetime of variable `p` if it is declared as `extern int p;`

Is it static, dynamic, automatic or it has no lifetime because there is no linkage?

Comment: The lifetime is like static.

Comment: @i486: Please don't answer in the comments section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Answers section requires more words :)

Comment: @i486: Yes, it would be a very short (too short!) answer. Still, it doesn't belong in the comments! Comments are not peer reviewed or quality controlled, which is a problem when someone posts a wrong answer, like you did :)

Comment: here's the explanaion:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280895/understanding-extern-storage-class-specifier-in-c/38281534?noredirect=1#comment63982076_38281534

Comment: @Kuldeep1007tanwar  Thanks and this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or it has no lifetime because there is no linkage?

The keyword `extern` means a variable is only declared, that is no storage is allocated for it [1].

The keyword `extern` has got nothing to do with the life time of a variable. That said, the life time/scope of a variable depends only on where exactly it occurs in the code.

**Note**

[1] When `extern` is used with an assignment like

```
extern int i=5;
```

the keyword  `extern` is ignored and the usual scope rules apply to the variable

[2] Please check my other [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280895/understanding-extern-storage-class-specifier-in-c/38281600#38281600) on this.

---

<sup>**Interesing**: As Stephen Prata in his book C++ Primer Plus puts it, the keyword `extern` means "Use the variable by this name previously defined externally"</sup>

Comment: You say that the life time of a variable  depends only on where exactly it occurs in the code. Then, it means that if the variable is declared within some function, it has automatic life time. Answers by others suggest that extern variable has static life time. So, it doesn't have to be only static lifetime?

Comment: @lightness-races-in-orbit : I meant to say `declared-only`. but thanks this makes sense.

Comment: @display_error: There is no such thing as an "extern variable", and the other answers do say that.

Comment: @sjsam What if extern int p; is declared in some function?

Comment: @display_error : It roughly means you're borrowing `p` which is declared somewhere else in your code. For example if `p`  is defined outside all the functions, then it will have its lifetime till the completion of the program. But the changes you make to p will affect its value too..

Comment: @sjsam I meant, will the lifetime in that case be static or automatic or dependent on linkage?

Answer (score 8):

Talking about the lifetime of the name introduced by the `extern` declaration doesn't make much sense - storage duration is a property of *objects*, not of *names*.

On the other hand, an `extern` variable declaration can only refer to a global variable, which has static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

C11 draft section 6.2.4 says

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Comment: Nice. As a side note the keyword `static` is meant only for linkage except when used in `block scope`.

Answer (score 0):

Life time of the programm. Initialized once at load time or programm startup. Default initial value is 0. Cannot be initialized inside the block.